# Where are these byte[]? (In Java using JProfiler)

Tags: java, jprofiler

I'm profiling a Java program that is leaking memory. Using JProfiler I see I get crazy amount of byte[] data. Is there a way to know more information about it? When is it allocated/created, where is it?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to find the path to the GC root of those arrays, this should tell you what they are used for.